# Handling GWT History and Fragment Identifiers

Tags: gwt, gwt-history

I have a GWT application that accept these tokens:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/app.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#user&someuser
```

This will open up a view (as in MVC) which works just fine. However, the problem is that the view has menus that can trigger to change to another view, like to switch to the user profile, etc. The URL above sticks but the content of the page is completely changed.

Is there a way to handle browser back button in this case. Back button works fine switching back to views triggered by URL fragments (by typing in the Browser address bar), like switching to `#user&someuser` to `#profile`

A problem however when the view is changed from menu or button events. Is there a way to emulate the same effect as if user has typed URL fragments manually? Such that back button will work. BTW, each URL fragment is associated to one view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for `History.newItem(newToken)` (or `History.newItem(newtoken, false)` if you don't want it to fire an event).

If it's not too late in your project, I'd suggest you use GWT Places though instead of `History`, and possibly GWT Activities (depending on your needs).
I wrote a few articles about these a while back, when they were introduced into GWT 2.1:

- http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-places/
- http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-places-part-ii/
- http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-activities/
- http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-activities-nesting-yagni/

Comment: Nice articles, I thought Places has to go with MVP and I need to revamp my application.

Comment: Anyway, in your answer, do you mean that I will call History.newItem(newToken, false) just before the application changes to another view?

Comment: I tried History.newItem and it works fine. However, it can browse back to "profile" view even if when the user logs out through the static main menu.

Comment: It's up to your app to handle the case when some _place_ is reached when the user is not signed in when it should be; same as a secured web page (think Facebook or GMail for instance) redirecting to the login screen.